# on multiple auth in laravel laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have  this code in the user model class
using this code showing error
Showing like this
[model class code](https://flareapp.io/share/oPR96xkm)

```
 
    protected function type(): Attribute
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn ($value) =>  ["user", "admin", "manager"][$value],
        );
    }
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using? You need v8.0 for this.

Answer (score 0):

As @Marwelln mentioned you would need PHP8 and you are are using php7.4. (See picture from the link you posted)

You can do `Attribute:get(fn($value) =>....)` instead

[image]